# center a div with html2pdf

Tags: php, html2pdf

I have the following code:

```
$html2pdf = new HTML2PDF('P', 'A4', 'en');
        $html2pdf->setDefaultFont('Arial');
        $html2pdf->writeHTML(utf8_encode($this->renderPartial('portlet', array('name' => $name, 'email' => $email), true)), false);
        $html2pdf->Output("test.pdf");
```

Now I want to put the generated content exactly in the middle of the page (the returned content it`s a div with some html elements). How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: Hi, please always remember to Google first. Searching for `center a div with html2pdf` seems to provide a number of satisfactory solutions. Thanks!

Comment: I would try to center HTML with CSS first and output it with html2pdf.